# RemoveDiffs production flag option does not remove all occurences of the Runtime Version added to generated files

Tags: codefluent

Using the default production flag options both the file generation date and the Runtime Version are displayed as shown below:

**Notice that the Build Version is listed twice**

```
// CodeFluent Entities generated (http://www.softfluent.com). Date: Thursday, 28 January 2016 13:41.
// Build:1.0.61214.0805
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("CodeFluent Entities", "1.0.61214.0805")]
```

When I set defaultProducerProductionFlags to "Default, Overwrite, RemoveDates" it still displays one of the build numbers

```
// CodeFluent Entities generated (http://www.softfluent.com). Date: .
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("CodeFluent Entities", "1.0.01234.05678")]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CodeFluent Entities build number cannot be removed totally. If you have a closer look, the build number is a "magic" sequence:

> 1.0.0**1234**.0**5678**

This is used to avoid merge conflicts in source control, and is guaranteed to never change.

Comment: Thanks, everything was working correctly all along. I did not realize that the GeneratedCodeAttribute for "CodeFluent Entities" was swapped from the build # to the value guaranteed never to change. All makes sense now.